# What is the best way to search a SharePoint 2013 list with more than 5k items?

Tags: search-results, list-view-threshold

We are migrating content from SP 2007 to SP 2013. We have many lists that have more than 5k items... some of which we need to be able to search all items. If we use the "find an item" search it only searches the items in that view (<5k) and the user experience is not good. The only way we can figure out how to search **all items** is using the new Content Search web part, which is not the easiest to configure and the OOTB display templates aren't very good.

Before I start creating a bunch of Content Search web parts and custom display templates I would like to know if we are headed in the right direction? is there a different, better way to be able to search all items in a list?

Thanks! MP

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this could be creating SharePoint indexes on searchable columns from List Settings -> Indexed Columns (/_layouts/IndexedColumns.aspx?List={guid}).
If lists have constantly creating/updating items, this is not a good idea. 
In any case the best way of searching list items in large list is to use Search API and CSWP is one of the most convenient ways to implement such solution. 
So, you're heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Their are many ways to handle the large lists.
Here are few Options:

1. Create **index for the column to be filtered** by. For example, create
   an index on “State” column, then create a view filtered by “State”.
   But if the items for this view is more than $5,000, it does not
   work; It only works on views with less than 5,000 items.
2. Use folders to hold items; Each folders can have 5,000 items;
3. Datasheet Views can display 50,100 items; (You browser must support
   ActiveX Control; Datasheet views doesn’t not work if you have
   Microsoft Office 64bits and Internet Explorer 64 bits)
4. Administrator can set up a “Daily Time Window” in Central
   Administration – General Settings – Throttle Management”. During
   this time window, you can view large lists, and you can only create
   index for large lists in this time window, unless you have special
   permission.
5. User “**Key Filters**” to filter the list;
6. “Open with Access”

https://lyndzhang.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/working-with-large-lists-in-sharepoint/

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-lists-V-Techniques-for-managing-large-lists-13456600-ff66-46ec-a2d2-91736d4a166e?section=7&CorrelationId=f4d8915d-1927-4bc9-a103-088deb6f8586&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: 2013 doesn't use ActiveX. Your #2 bullet is a head scratcher...